# c++ how to get a pointer to the current object in another class?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, shared-ptr, coredump

And again a bad-formulted question, but I don't know how to shortly explain this situation:

I have two classes. Let's name them A and B. A has a lot of member variables and methods. B is a struct which has a shared_pointer to an object of type A. Now A has a method that returns an instance of B (with a pointer to the current instance of A).

My problem is, that A is the subclass of C. C has the same method as described above as pure virtual. The code would look like this:

```
class C {
public:
  virtual B mymethod() const =0;
  virtual int getMyvar() const =0;
};

class A : public C {
public:
  B mymethod() const override;
  int getMyvar() const override;   //outputs myvar
private:
  int myvar;
};

struct B {
  std::shared_ptr<C> pointer;
};

B A::mymethod() const {
  B instance;
  instance.pointer = std::make_shared<A>(*this);   //is this wrong?
  return instance;
}
```

My compiler (gcc 4.8.2) creates the executables for the following code, but at runtime I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)":

```
void AnotherClass::something() const {
  A object;
  B instance = object.mymethod();
  std::cout << instance.pointer->getMyvar();   //dumps the core womehow?
}
```

I read about the [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) but I could not figure out how it works or if it helps me.

Why do I get the error message and how can I fix this?

Comment: object.mymethod();  // you're missing function call

Comment: yeah, hah... =D
No this is a simple example. My script is too complicated to post, but this example explains it well. I can't reach the original object in my case... =(

Comment: okay, sorry, edited XD Just forgot it, but the error is still there =(

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. Could you post a complete example which shows the error?

Comment: `myvar` is not in C and it is not accessible even in A.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to fix the myvar error... it's just in this example not in my code -.-

Comment: Your make_shared calls the copy constructor of A, so you don't return a pointer to the current instance, but rather a pointer to a newly created copy.

Comment: @DanielJour could you please explain what I should do instead? =)

Comment: Ivella's answer seems to correctly address that.

Comment: 5 answers and 18 comments definitively show that it's a really interesting question !  Only 1 upvote ?

Comment: Okay, state of the error: I need to implement a move-constructor or a copy-constructor... I'll do this tomorrow as it's 1:33am here and I have to stand up early. Next updates will come in 8-10 hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have read [in the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), you do:

```
class A : public C, std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
  B mymethod() override; // Notice the lack of const
private:
  int myvar;
};
```

and then:

```
B A::mymethod() {
  B instance;
  instance.pointer = shared_from_this();   // this should be right
  return instance;
}
```

Like this, all the instances of a `std::shared_ptr` to the same A object will share the same reference counter, and it will be destroyed only when it must be.

EDIT:

Also, notice that your object A must be managed by some other `std::shared_ptr` before you can call `A::mymethod()`. I.e. you must create A objects like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> a_obj(new A);
```

then you can call `A::mymethod()`:

```
B b_obj = a_obj->mymethod();
```

EDIT2:

Method `A::mymethod()` (and consequently, `C::mymethod()`) can't be `const` to be able to call the non-`const` method `shared_from_this()`.

Comment: The compiler tells me "std::enable_shared_from_this<A> is an inaccessible base of A" when I compile this...? o.O

Comment: Instead of `obj(new A);` i used `std::make_shared<A>(...)`. Is that a problem?

Comment: Oops. Method `A::mymethod()` can't be `const`, because `shared_from_this()` isn't `const` either. That makes sense (maybe?), because `shared_from_this()` needs to alter the internally held reference counter.

Comment: It is ok to use `std::make_shared<A>(...)`, just have it managed by a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I deleted all const signs, but its still he same error message telling "'std::enable_shared_from_this<A>' is an inaccessible base of 'A'"

Comment: Well, without looking at your real code or the error message, I can't diagnose the problem. My code compiles without warning: http://pastebin.com/K6d0SrYh

Comment: You may try declaring the inheritance as public:
`class A : public C, public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {`

Comment: declaring as public helps fixing the error. Now I can compile and link the executable. At runtime I get segmentation fault again -.- I tried shared_from_this() and even this->shared_from_this, always a dumped core... You can find the project on my friend's github, the files are shape.*, sphere.*, box.*, triangle.* and the object creation is in sdfloader.hpp in directory framework -> [github.com](https://github.com/yorrickslr/programmiersprachen-raytracer)

Comment: As B refers to C, enable_shared_from_this is potentially relevant for all classes derived from C.  I'd suggest to make C inherit (publicly) from it instead of using multiple inheritance on A.

Comment: Fixed everything, had another mistake too, also thanks to @Christophe, would be the second accepted answer =)

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary problem: how do you down-cast to access myvar ?**

***Edit:*** after your edit, this first topic is no longer relevant.  I leave it because I used this code in the live demos illustrating how to solve it.

First, the statement that causes the dump can't compile as you gave it:

```
std::cout << instance.pointer->myvar;
```

because `instance.pointer` is a `shared_ptr<C>` and `C` has no member `myvar`.

If downcasting properly with `dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(instance.pointer)->myvar`  (supposing `AnotherClass` is a friend) it works.

**Your shared pointer made a clone: is it your intent ?**

This statement:

```
instance.pointer = std::make_shared<A>(*this);   //is this wrong? PERHAP'S !?
```

creates a clone object obtained by copy construction from `*this`.  So you don't reference the original object `A`, and hence you don't need `std::enable_shared_from_this` :  the use count of `instance.pointer` will be 1 because at that moment there's only one reference to the newly created shared object.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/LJM31t)

**Or do you want it to reference the original object ?**

You then have to change the statement to:

```
instance.pointer = std::shared_ptr<A>(this);   //better ?
```

But this won't compile because `mymethod()` is const, so it consider `this` as being a pointer to const.  To compile the statement you must either remove the constness of `mymethod()` or add constness to B's pointer.

Then it works.  B's shared pointer has still a use count of 1, which is again ok. But once this shared_ptr gets out of scope, the use count is 0 and the shared_ptr's destructor will try to delete the object.  AS IT WAS INITIALY A LOCAL OBJECT (ON STACK) this causes a runtime error.

**Final approach**

As you want to have shared pointers to your object,  the code of `AnotherClass` should be something like:

```
shared_ptr<C> pobject(new A);  // create the object from the free store
B instance = pobject->mymethod(); 
...
```

And the C class must inherit as follows:

```
class C : public std::enable_shared_from_this<C> 
{...}
```

And the my method class must initialize the shared_pointer it retures as follows:

```
//instance.pointer = std::shared_ptr<A>(this);    // no, don't do no longer !! 
instance.pointer = shared_from_this();  //<===== RETURN A POINTER TO SELF
```

Then everything works perfectly.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/rO5o2J)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would get a memory error when your objects go out of scope. 
When you create your object A and then create your shared_ptr with the this pointer, your counter will be 1 instead of 2 (as you would maybe expect). So A will be destroyed twice, instead of once.
A more  correct way of doing this would be create class A as a shared_ptr and initialize the pointer in class B with it (not inside class A). This way the counter will be incremented as you expect and A will be deleted only once.

Comment: In fact, the runtime error happens when the shared_ptr tries to delete a local object (i.e that was not created with new).  Proof of concept [here](https://ideone.com/bGwWk3).

Comment: It will probably depend on the order your objects go out of scope. If B goes out of scope before A, then A will cause the stack corruption.

Answer (score 0):

The class you want to share will need to inherit from enable_share_from_this.
Then you can call share_from_this to obtain a shared pointer to the class you're in.

If you just try and make_shared you just create a separate ownership group that will mean two things will try and delete your object. That will be the cause of your segfault.